# How to aggregate documents with `$in` in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

There are my documents :

```
> db.messages.find({})

 {   "_id" : ObjectId("5c1f9e3d37e9e12650b9971a"), 
"groupId" : ObjectId("5c0fe59f5dcbbe30b732616c"), 
"content" : "hi"
}
{   "_id" : ObjectId("5c1f9e3d37e9e12650b9971a"), 
    "groupId" : ObjectId("5c0fe59f5dcbbe30b732616c"), 
   "content" : "hello"
}
{   "_id" : ObjectId("5c1f9e3d37e9e12650b9971a"), 
"groupId" : ObjectId("5c0fe59f5dcbbe30b732616d"), 
"content" : "hi"
}
 {   "_id" : ObjectId("5c1f9e3d37e9e12650b9971a"), 
  "groupId" : ObjectId("5c0fe59f5dcbbe30b732616e"), 
  "content" : "hi"
}
```

one group has many messages .
now I has groupIds like:
[ObjectId("5c0fe59f5dcbbe30b732616c"),ObjectId("5c0fe59f5dcbbe30b732616d")]

I want to find the latest one message using `$in` with sql like :

```
SELECT * FROM `message` WHERE `groupId` IN (xx,xx) group by 
groupId order by id desc .
```

how to do it with mongo shell ?

Comment: `db.collection.find({ groupId: { $in: [ObjectId("5c0fe59f5dcbbe30b732616c"),ObjectId("5c0fe59f5dcbbe30b732616d")] }}).sort({ createdAt: -1 }).limit(1)`

Comment: I need one groupId to one MessageId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first [**`$sort`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) with the `createdAt` field to get the latest message in the [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage using the [**`$first`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "groupId": { "$in": [ObjectId("5c0fe59f5dcbbe30b732616c"), ObjectId("5c0fe59f5dcbbe30b732616d")] }}},
  { "$sort": { "createdAt": -1 }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$groupId",
    "content": { "$first": "$content" }
  }}
])
```